# Не биндится метод

Tags: java, android, android-data-binding

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в TextView не биндится метод? Выводится пустое значение текста в виджете.

#### fragment_beat_box.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.bignerdranch.android.beatbox.SoundViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="@{viewModel.textViewText}"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:padding="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

#### SoundViewModel.java

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.beatbox;

import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable;
import androidx.databinding.Bindable;

public class SoundViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    private Sound mSound;
    private BeatBox mBeatBox;
    //private String mTextViewText;

    public SoundViewModel(BeatBox beatBox) {
        mBeatBox = beatBox;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getTitle() {
        return mSound.getName();
    }

    public Sound getSound() {
        return mSound;
    }

    public void setSound(Sound sound) {
        mSound = sound;
        notifyChange();
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getTextViewText() {
        return "hello";
    }

    public void onButtonClicked() {
        mBeatBox.play(mSound);
    }
}
```

#### BeatBoxFragment.java

```
...
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentBeatBoxBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_beat_box, container, false);
        binding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));
        binding.recyclerView.setAdapter(new SoundAdapter(mBeatBox.getSounds()));        
        return binding.getRoot();
    }
...
```

Comment: ну а ViewModel в binding проставили? `binding.setViewModel(viewModel);`

Comment: Спасибо, привязка появилась!